Surrogate variable analysis for paired RNA seq experiment
I have an RNAseq experiment with 1000s of samples. Each sample comes from a patient and was treated either with a drug or DMSO (as control).
I am currently deciding between SVA and RUVseq to account for "hidden" technical variation.
My question is, if I have identified surrogate variables (regardless of method) and include them in my model like this:
design = ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + ... + condition

Will the surrogate variables also account for the fact that I have a "paired" design (each sample has a control and a treated counterpart)?
Any insights are very much appreciated!
Cheers!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
